# Deploying application to client with debug/crash reports

Tags: c++, windows, ubuntu, debugging, remote-debugging

I have created a Qt application that can be compiled both in Linux and Windows. Moreover, using [Qt installer framework](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/index.html) I have created installers for both OS. However, my application still has some bugs. I know how to debug them using a debugger on my computer, but when somebody installs it using the installers that I created, there is no way for me to track the segmentation faults that might happen in the end-user computer.

There are some programs that do some kind of crash-log so when they crash a log file can be sent to the developer to try to find out the problem. I could achieve something like that by adding a logging system in my application that logs (print to a file) what the user is doing at all time in my application. However, this is a pretty complicated way and involves a lot of writting in my end. To me, it looks like there should be some kind of automatic tool to "run your programs in debug mode" (i.e. create a crash report) in the computers where your application is installed. **Does anybody know of a way of creating crash reports on computers where the application that you developed is only installed but not compiled?** I assume I would have to compile my project in RelWithDebInfo to achieve something in this field, which is not a problem.

Comment: For Windows: [Collecting User-Mode Dumps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For automatic crash report on the major platforms (Windows, Mac OS, Linux), you could use the open source libraries [Google Breakpad](https://github.com/google/breakpad) (used in Firefox for example), or the more modern [Google Crashpad](https://chromium.googlesource.com/crashpad/crashpad/+/master/README.md) (used in Chromium for example). These two C++ libraries will generate a MiniDump file on crash which can be send to a distant server if you want.

For example, here a basic Qt application integrating Google Crashpad:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets/qapplication.h>
#include <QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h>

#include <client/crashpad_client.h>

void initializeCrashpad()
{
    const auto dataDir = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppLocalDataLocation);
    const auto db = dataDir + "/metrics/db";
    const auto metrics = dataDir + "/crash/metrics";
    const auto url = "https://my-http-server.com/"

    QDir().mkpath(db);
    QDir().mkpath(metrics);

    crashpad::CrashpadClient::StartHandler(
        "crashpad_handler.exe", // Relative path to a Crashpad handler executable
        db.toStdWString(), // Directory to Crashpad database 
        metrics.toStdWString(), // Directory where metrics files can be stored
        url.toStdString(), // URL of the HTTP upload server
        {}, // Annonations to include in the crash report
        true, // The program will be restarted if it crash
        true);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    initializeCrashpad();

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow window;
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Then you will need to ship your application with `crash_handler.exe` (or whatever you have called it), or implement this little program using `crashpad::HandlerMain()`. For more information search on Google, or read the Crashpad documentation.

Otherwise, you can use the free/non-free service [Backtrace.io](https://backtrace.io/) or [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) which provides tutorials to integrate Crashpad into your application, and provides also an upload server, with many tools.

Comment: I successfully integrated crashpad. However, I cannot configure the upload server. Is there any tutorial on how to do that?

Comment: If you want to write your own HTTP crash collect server, you can see here for an example: https://github.com/chromiumembedded/cef/blob/master/tools/crash_server.py (in Python). You could also use the Socorro system from Mozilla which permits crash collect and analyse and use one of the non-free services mentionned in the answer.

Comment: Crashpad uploads the crash report with a HTTP POST and the content type 'multipart/form-data'. The upload is exactly like a file upload from a HTML <input type="file"> field.

Comment: What can I do to read the crash reports in Linux? I've [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60394317/google-crashpad-on-a-cross-compilation-platform-application-cannot-read-dmp-fil) about this that maybe you can have a look at.