# Google crashpad on a cross-compilation platform application. Cannot read dmp file in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debugging, gdb, minidump

I have a small [qt project](https://github.com/apalomer/qt_crashpad_test) with a segmentation fault that I want to track (this is an example and the segmentation fault is manually added for testing purposes, in the real project I do not know the segfaults left there). I decided to use google crashpad so I can create minidump files and then track the issues on my computer. I have been successful in doing so in windows with the example project. However, I am cannot open the *dmp* files in Linux to debug them.

I have tried using [minidump-2-core](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/62.0.3178.1/docs/linux_minidump_to_core.md) as explained in [this blog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_a_minidump) on the section **Using minidump-2-core on Linux**. However, when I run this command I get the following error: `This minidump was not generated by Linux or NaCl.` Obviously I am using the same computer with Ubuntu 18.04 for running the code that generates the *dmp* file and to convert it to a core file.

Any idea on how can I convert the *dmp* files into something that I can put into gdb for debugging? Or mor in general, how to proceed with tese files created by google crashpad in linus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to build `minidump_stackwalk` which is a command line tool from the Breakpad repository. You'll also need to generate `.sym` files using `dump_syms` which is another tool from the Breakpad repository.

Once you have generated the `.sym` files you'll need to lay them out on disk following the convention `/path/to/symbols/folder/MODULE_NAME/MODULE_ID/MODULE_NAME.sym`.

Once the symbol files have been laid out in the correct folder structure you can invoke `minidump_stackwalk` which will output a symbolicated stack trace and a list of modules that were loaded at runtime:

```
./minidump_stackwalk -m /path/to/minidump.dmp /path/to/symbols/folder
```

More information on how to use `minidump_stackwalk` can be found [here](https://www.bugsplat.com/docs/sdk/crashpad/building/#symbolicating).

More information about how to use `dump_syms` can be found [here](https://www.bugsplat.com/docs/sdk/crashpad/building/#generating-symbols).

Comment: is there a way to get the module_id automatically? Thanks to your instructions I've managed to get the information out of the minidump into a textile. However, I have lots of libraries and getting the right `path/to/symbols/folder` structure would be very tedious to do manually. The only thing missing is to get the  `MODULE_ID` automatically for me.

Comment: I've seen now that it can be parsed from the `.sym` file itself.